# Como fazer um select no MYSQL, trazendo resultados agrupados

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreach

Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne o valor parecido com o abaixo:

```
TIPO 1
unidade 1
unidade 2
unidade n

TIPO 2 
unidade 1
unidade 2
unidade n
```

As tabelas etão assim:

```
tabela_tipo
id|tipo
1 |TIPO 1
2 |TIPO 2

tabela_unidades
id|idtipo|unidade
1 |  1   |unidade 1
2 |  1   |unidade 2
3 |  2   |unidade 1
4 |  2   |unidade 2
```

estou usando PHP e mysql, o jeito que sei, é fazer um `foreach` dentro do resultado, fazendo assim várias consultas, mas acredito que deva existir alguma forma de não precisar fazer varias consultas, abaixo como está atualmente:

```
$result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela_tipos" );
$tipos = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
foreach($tipos as $t){
    echo $t['tipo'].'<br/>';;
    $result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela_unidades WHERE idtipo = {$t['id']}" );
    $unidades = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    foreach($unidades as $u){
        echo $u['unidade'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Faça um INNER JOIN entre tabela_tipo e tabela_unidades com tabela_tipo.id = tabela_unidades.idtipo e ordene o resultado por tabela_tipo.id e tabela_unidades.id que resultará em uma tabela com todos os dados desejados..Quanto a forma de exibição você faz no PHP com o devido controle de quebras.

Comment: mas dessa forma, vai trazer uma lista com tudo, certo? como faço para separa em blocos pelo tipo?

Comment: Como disse anteriormente: "Quanto a forma de exibição você faz no PHP com o devido controle de quebras."

Answer (score 0):

mais ou menos assim

```
$result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela_tipos INNER JOIN tabela_unidades ON tabela_tipo.id = tabelas_unidades.idtipo" );
$tipos = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

com o array *$tipos* você consegue fazer o foreach, mas basicamente você terá que fazer igual já fez, porém com uma única chamada ao banco de dados (oq se for um sistema com MUITAS requisições será ótimo para seu servidor)